# Sort Coordinates from top left to bottom right

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv, coordinates, led

I extracted 110 coordinates from contours of a 10x11 LED-Array using C++ and OpenCV and stored them in a vector. Now I want to sort them from top left to bottom right to detect if a LED in a certain row and column is on. I presorted the coordinates by y-position to make sure that the first 10 coordinates in the vector representing the first LED row in my Image.

```
vector<Point2f> centers;

bool compareY(Point2f p1, Point2f p2){
if(p1.y < p2.y) return true;
if(p1.y > p2.y) return false;
}

sort(centers.begin(), centers.end(), compareY);
```

Now I have to sort them by x-position. The problem is that the x-position from the first LED in row two or any other row can be a bit smaller then the first LED in row one. Due to that fact they have to be sorted from centers[0] to centers[9], centers[10] to centers[20]... row by row. Has anybody an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Managed to sort the points but my algorithm based on contour detection is not robust enough to detect all LEDs. Has anyone an idea for a robust method to detect them?

Comment: is the position wrong because of perspective effects or because of not optimal hardware layout of the LED positions? If the first one applies you could create the pattern virtually and try some pattern matching to find a slightly rotated LED grid.

Comment: First of all: what does your `compareY` function return in case of `p1.y == p2.y`? You should use `else` instead of the second `if` or better just return the boolean `p1.y < p2.y`. Secondly if you want to sort the vector from `centers[0]` to `centers[9]` you just do `sort(centers.begin(),centers.begin()+10,compareX)` since you can perform additions for vector::iterator.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/31515/sorting-contours-from-left-to-right-and-top-to/

Comment: You have UB if the Y coordnates are the same. Just `return p1.y < p2.y;`.

Comment: it's because of perspective effects and the fact that the contours have slightly different center coordinates due to erode/dilate.

Comment: I tried some template matching but i didn't found a proper way to extract all coordinates from the 110 LEDs.

Comment: Hi have you solved this? can you please post your Answer?

Comment: I first sorted them by Y and then row by row to X.

    bool LedCounter::sortByY(const KeyPoint &a, const KeyPoint &b){

    if(a.pt.y < b.pt.y){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool LedCounter::sortByX(const KeyPoint &a, const KeyPoint &b){

    if(a.pt.x < b.pt.x){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

sort(blobKeypoints.begin(), blobKeypoints.end(), sortByY);

int count = 0;

while(count <= 100){
            sort(blobKeypoints.begin()+count, blobKeypoints.begin()+count+10, sortByX);
            count += 10;
        }

Comment: The problem of robustness is because you have is the points are not well aligned with each other. You may need to use distance formulas (yes, I mean Pythagoras Theorem and square root) to compute the nearest point.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to perform a lexicographical sorting by Y coordinate and then X coordinate, you just have to provide a suitable comparison function that really implements a strict weak ordering using. For example

```
#include <tuple>

bool compareYX(const Point2f& p1, const Point2f& p2)
{
  return std::tie(p1.y, p1.x) < std::tie(p2.y, p2.x);
}
```

You can also implement the lexicographical comparison manually, but this is quite error-prone.

Comment: For some reason #include <tuple> dont provide tie function.

Comment: @user3797009 Strange, it should. Do you have full C++11 support? Otherwise, `<tr1/tuple>` and `std::tr1::tie`.

Comment: @user3797009 If you have full C++11 support, then this should work. So you don't, or there is another problem in your code.

Comment: Forgot to set -std=c++11 in my .pro file. Now tie works but the sort is still incorrect.

Comment: @user3797009 Maybe add some example coordinates before and after the sorting, to clarify how you want to sort the points.