# Sorting Vector<Points> from Top to Bottom then from Left to Right using STL in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to sort a `vector<Point>` in Top to bottom & then by left to right order. This question is possible duplicate of [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528285/sort-coordinates-from-top-left-to-bottom-right). Is there any STL based sorting method available for this Co-Ordinate sorting?

I've also tried this code & failed:

```
bool compareYX(const Point2f& p1, const Point2f& p2)
{
  return std::tie(p1.y, p1.x) < std::tie(p2.y, p2.x);
}
```

[image]

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: A set of arbitrary points (x,y pairs), before, then *after*, sorting, would go a LONG way in describing your problem in detail. Also, "failed" is not a description; its a state. *How* did the posted comparator not result in the order you wanted? Did it not *compile*, or simply not emit the order desired?

Comment: Why did you "fail" with `compareYX` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
// for sorting first by Y descending and later by X ascending
bool compareYX(const Point2f& p1, const Point2f& p2) {
    return std::tie(p2.y, p1.x) < std::tie(p1.y, p2.x);
}
```

In this case you would be sorting by `Y` first in descending order, see that `p2.y` is at the left and `p1.y` at the right and later by `X` in ascending orders

Input Points:

```
{ {-2, 1}, {1,1}, {-1,-5}, {4,-2}, {5, 5} }
```

Output Order:

```
(5,5)
(-2,1)
(1,1)
(4,-2)
(-1,-5)
```